# how to remove message "You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK"

Tags: asp.net-core

When I rebuild solution, message appears

```
    You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project
```

I created a global.json containing

```
    {
        "sdk": {
            "version": "2.1.4"
        }
    }
```

Then in cli,

```
    dotnet --version
```

outputs

```
    2.1.4
```

Then in cli,

```
    dotnet --list-sdks
```

outputs

```
    2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.200-preview-007474 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.200-preview-007576 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    2.1.300-preview2-008533 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

In my .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.4" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="nlog.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

After changing the dotnet version by doing the above, I still get the message when I rebuild solution. How do I change the current version of .net core sdk I am using and remove that annoying message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this PR on github: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/2042

Basically you could do the following in your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <SuppressNETCoreSdkPreviewMessage>true</SuppressNETCoreSdkPreviewMessage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This hides the message, but does adding the global.json actually make sure it runs in the correct SDK version?

Comment: The global.json defines against which SDK version you are running your CLI commands. If you want to specify a specific runtime for your project you should look at Target frameworks : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: I see the warning if I build using Visual Studio but not from the command line. So Visual Studio does not respect the settings in `global.json` ?

Comment: For that you have to disable SDK roll forward to get Visual Studio to respect it.

Answer (score 2):

This message warns you about possible bugs and instabilities of using a preview sdk version.

You can force Visual studio (or cli) to use a non-preview sdk version. To do so
place a "global.json" file in your solution folder. you can create one using:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version <your_desired_sdk_version>
```