# How to convert an angular cli project to a dot net core project

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-cli, dotnet-core-pack

I have created a project using angular(6) cli now I want to convert it in dot net core project.

I have copied all files from angular-cli->src->app to angular.net-core->ClientApp->app.

I have installed all required packages including some :-

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install npm@latest -g
npm i rxjs
```

**Visual Studio version : VS 2017(15.6.6).**

When I run the project am getting error :

> Error: Cannot find module "./assets/img/ngx-bootstrap.svg" at webpackMissingModule

I am getting errors one by one and most of these belongs to packages, I am installing packages when i got any error, I may get next error if I resolve it.

What should be the required changes to make it run in dot.net core.

**Package.Json :**

```
{
  "name": "EFNgApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14"
  }
}
```

**Note :** When I build the application I am getting below message in output window.

> You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can
>   define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project.
>   More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452

Comment: angular cli is a typescript project, .NET Core is c#. How on earth are you going to convert that. Start a new project.

Comment: but we have a angular template in asp.net core which support typescript..

Comment: Isn't rxjs-compat a seperate library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat

Comment: its fixed i think, now getting another error, have updated question..

Comment: Check this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423404/how-to-remove-message-you-are-working-with-a-preview-version-of-the-net-core-s