# How to force Visual Studio to compile project against the release version of .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn

Lately I have noticed in the Output Window of Visual Studio that when I compile my solution I see this message:

> You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK

This seems odd to me since I'm not knowingly currently using a preview version of .NET Core SDK.  To explore this further, I created a new solution that contains one project based on the default Visual Studio "Class Library (.NET Core) project template.  Pretty plain vanilla.

[image].

Here is the total sum of the proj file:

[image]

And yet, when I build this project, I see "You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK" in the output window (see first screenshot).  What's up with that?  I'm using the latest production version of Visual Studio which currently is Version 16.8.5.

I see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423404/how-to-remove-message-you-are-working-with-a-preview-version-of-the-net-core-s) SO question is closely related to my question but unfortunately the poster simply asked how to make the message go away.  So the accepted answer is to suppress the message like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <SuppressNETCoreSdkPreviewMessage>true</SuppressNETCoreSdkPreviewMessage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But I don't want to just suppress the message if under the hood the compiler is really compiling against a preview SDK.  I want the compiler to stop using the preview SDK and use the one specified in the proj file.  Namely the the production `netcoreapp3.1` SDK.

Here are the SDKs I currently have installed:

[image]

So how do I make that happen and why is it not already happening?

Comment: Which SDKs do you have installed? `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: @Magnetron I just added that info.

Comment: @Magnetron  I hear ya.  The thing is my other project where I first noticed the issue is targeting net5.0 so it's less easy to say what it's compiling against given the message shown in the output window.

Comment: The 5.0 SDK (which is a preview) can build 3.1 apps. All SDKs can build all previous target frameworks. the 5.0 SDK is what is being selected here

Comment: unrelated but I would look at the dotnet uninstaller tool [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows#net-uninstall-tool). That should help cleaning up older SDKs which you do not need anymore

Comment: @JonathonMarolf That is a very insightful comment that helps me understand the situation much better.

Comment: Yeah, @JonathonMarolf is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. Tell Visual Studio that you do not want to use preview SDKs, this option can be found under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features. If this is unchecked Visual Studio will only use released SDKs to build your project

[image]

2. If you only want Visual Studio to use non-preview SDKs for some projects you can add a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file to the root folder of those projects. global.json files have many options to configure which SDK should be used to build a given project but for our purposes we just care about [allowPrerelease](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x#allowprerelease). Setting that to `false` will ensure your project (or solution) is only built with a released SDK.

NOTE: the defaults are different in different versions of Visual Studio. If you are using a Preview release of Visual Studio it will automatically use preview SDKs. If you are using a released build of Visual Studio it should prefer releases SDKs (unless the option shown in Tools->Options is checked).

Comment: This answer plus your comment on the question fully explains my situation and how to fix it.